# What is the language of my SQL Server setup files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server

Im trying to install SQL Server in my Windows Server in english . But got this error.

[image]

I look for a solution and say I have to change the setting on Control Panel to match my media.

[image]

The problem is not sure what is the lenguaje of my sql server install disk.

How can I know what is the lenguaje of my Setup Disk?

Comment: What language is your system set to?  Check "Region and Language" settings in the Control Panel to see that.

Comment: @MaxVernon I know my system is in english, but setup doesnt match that. I need change my system to match the lenguage in the setup media

Comment: Your screenshots don't show the system being English, and there are several variants of English, as well.

Comment: @MaxVernon I say `my Windows Server in english`  but again the suggest solution is change the windows location so match the one on the installer. Ok, I could try to download a different installer with english version.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Have you been able to determine the language of your current install? What is the directory name that starts with the 4-digit number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the root directory / folder of the install media, there should be several sub-directories/folders, including: x64, redist, resources, etc. One of those sub-directories will have a name starting with a 4-digit number and then 3 letters, possibly followed by another short group of letters:

```
####_AAA[_AA?]
```

That first group of 4-digits is the LCID, and the 3 letters are the language code. My installs for several versions now all have the following folder:

**1033_ENU_LP**

While the LCID is highly specific with regards to which language, the ENU portion at least matches the first pop-up you posted in the question that mentions:

> ... ENU localized files.

If you want to know what the LCID translates to, please see the following list on MSDN: [Locale IDs Assigned by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx). The number in the directory / folder name will match something in the far-right column: **LCID Dec**. For example, 1033 indicates a locale of: "English - United States".

Comment: I found the codes, have `1033_ENU_LP` and `3082_ESN_LP`, was weird english didnt work, But I went with `Spanish(Spain)` and works ok